# How to formate date from date picker IBOutlet before sending it to sqlite3 db

Tags: date, sqlite, format

I'm using the date picker to allow the user to select a date. This date then will then be inserted into a Sqlite3 db.

How do I format that date to "mm dd yyyy" before insertion?

Every thread on this board addresses formatting a date using NSDateFormatter, but they all start with [NSDate date] as the date to format. How do I format the "variable" date string from the date picker?

I do not want to format a "current date" string.

My coding background is Cold Fusion, but I stop programing about 7 years ago and just recently decided to try out XCode & Objective C. Please be gentle. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Date from DatePicker simply using `datepicker.date`

Try this,

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy"];
NSString *s=[df stringFromDate:dtPicker.date];

NSLog(@"date to store in sqlite3  db:%@",s);
```

Comment: Ok, this worked perfectly, only hade to change datePicker.date to dateSelect.date  / dateSelect is what I set when I declared the property as in my .h file. @property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateSelect;